# C++ Program crashes when string and int pointer are used together as function arguments

Tags: c++

I have a super weird problem with glibc on Ubuntu.

Sample program test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

bool abc(string unitstr,int *data)
{        

}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

  int *dd3 = new int(8); 
  dd3[0]=1;dd3[1]=2;dd3[2]=3;dd3[3]=4;
  dd3[4]=5;dd3[5]=6;dd3[6]=7;dd3[7]=8;
  abc("sss",dd3);

  return 1;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ test.cpp
a.out
```

Result:

```
a.out: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Abort (core dumped)
```

Comment: I love nice and easy-to-read C code in glibc. I think Mr Torvalds was right about them being misleaded concerning their coding style.

Comment: H2CO3, I fully agree with you! I myself do a lot of coding (have just finished 4000 lines of C++ code in the past week). But I really like simple and easy-to-read coding style and I can never understand why some people make their codes so difficult to understand. Maybe they think I am too naive? LOL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With this line:

```
int *dd3 = new int(8);
```

You're allocating and initializing a *scalar*, not an array: a single `int`, initialized with the *value* `8`.

You need:

```
int *dd3 = new int[8];
```

Answer (score 6):

```
int *dd3 = new int(8);
```

This statement only allocates space for a single integer (and then initializes it with the number 8). You then proceed in using this pointer like a larger array, leading to undefined behavior that may (and indeed, seems to) manifest itself later on.

Using `new` here seems unnecessary (and exception-unsafe, if nothing else). Just use a `vector` and be done with it (should you want to be able to resize the block inside the function, just pass the vector instead of a pointer).

Comment: Thanks so much eq-!!!! Yes, I don't have to use pointer in this example. But my actual program is quite complex and some times the array can be very big. So I guess simple pointer should be better for that.

Answer (score 6):

This line allocates a **single** `int` and initializes it to the value `8`:

```
int *dd3 = new int(8);
```

If you want an array of 8 `ints` do this instead:

```
int *dd3 = new int[8];
```

Don't forget to correctly return the memory when you are done:

```
delete [] dd3;
```